# How to move string slice reference to a function so that it's lifetimes dies inside the function passed?

Tags: rust

So in the below function I didn't use `&content` while passing the parameter to `func`. How is `content` available after `func(content)`?

How do you move the `content` reference to `func` so that the reference dies inside the `func` and will not be available afterwards the call if that even makes sense? I want to just free the memory afterwards.

```
fn main() {
    let content = "Hello World";
    func(content);

    println!("{}", content);
}

fn func(string: &str) {
    println!("{}", &string);
}
```

Comment: content is a static literal. Your reference points to the code, not to any allocated memory. There's no memory to clean here.

Comment: Oh okay. So when I passed `content` to `func` does that mean it copied the string or just using the reference even without doing `&content`? @DenysSéguret

Comment: You just gave a lightweight reference to `func`.

Comment: Gotcha. So for static literals you don't have to do say `&content` right? You could just do `content` while passing to the function (to give reference I mean). Both are same right?

Comment: Yes, content is already a `&'static str`.

Comment: Oh okay. Now I get that `&'static` thingy. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: @Damon Correct - `content` is _already_ a reference, and `&content` would be a reference to reference (`&&str`).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a couple misunderstandings in the comments. The fact that you can call `func(content)` and still use `content` has **nothing** to do with the fact that `content` has a static lifetime. It has to do with the fact that immutable references implement [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), so they can't be "moved." It's like how this code works despite not having any static references:

```rust
fn func<T>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = &x;
    
    func(y);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

Even *if* you have something large that you want to eventually free, you don't need to do anything with the reference. Once the scope is exited (e.g. the function returns), Rust will drop all local variables, freeing any memory if necessary.